# How can I position a layout right above the android on-screen keyboard?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-linearlayout

See the attached photo. Twitter does it well. They have a layout, which I will call a toolbar for lack of a better term, right above the onscreen keyboard. How can I do this with my code?

[image]

UPDATE:
**Here is my layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/actionbarRelativeLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/actionbar_gradient">
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/stocktwits" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/charCountTextView" android:text="140" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="18sp" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_centerVertical="true"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/composeEditText" android:focusable="true" android:hint="Share an idea with the community" android:gravity="left|top" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"></EditText>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/border" android:background="#c4c4c4" android:baselineAligned="false" android:layout_height="1dp"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/toolbarLinearLayout" android:orientation="horizontal" android:padding="5dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/gray_toolbar_gradient">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/shortenButton" android:background="@drawable/shortenbutton" android:layout_weight="0"></Button>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
        <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/twitterCheckBox" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_weight="0" android:background="@drawable/twittergraybutton"></CheckBox>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0" android:id="@+id/sendButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/sharebutton"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**And here is my Manifest where I specify the softInputMode:**

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Make sure your [soft input mode is set to adjustResize](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft), then place the layout with your toolbar at the bottom of your activity.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/my_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- Your content here -->
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- Your toolbar items here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I made my soft input mode set to adjustResize. No luck unfortunately.

Comment: Change the `layout_height="fill_parent"` on your EditText to `layout_height="0dip"` and let the weight handle it.

Comment: I had `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);` in onCreate() which messed everything up. removing this line in conjunction with your recommendations have worked.

Answer (score 11):

This is for people who after setting the adjustResize still did not work, there is an article:
[adjustResize does not work in fullscreen](http://aubykhan.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/android-development-tips-resizing-layout-while-on-screen-keyboard-is-displayed/)

I indeed had this set to fullscreen, when setting my theme back to a nonfullscreen theme the layouts resized just as wanted.

Comment: +10 thanks for the tip. You have to use Theme.Holo.NoActionBar instead.

Comment: I've searched quite a lot for this answer. Thank you ! This answer should be marked as correct.

Comment: I have spent more than 10 hours at last some consolation here.

Answer (score 0):

Important **addition** to the answers above.

When you work with **DialogFragment** fullscreen is applied **implicitly**.

That means that you have to:
1) set style in onCreate() of your DialogFragment:

```
public class YourDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_NoActionBar);
        }
}
```

2) if you use your own theme you should handle it like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
```