# Put element above the keyboard of Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have an application in Html5 + PhoneGap ..

I want that when you click on a particular element to put it over the keyboard of Android, it is possible to do it via JS?(possible to do it at all?!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interact with the OS by developping a phonegap plugin, but it requires some JAVA code, but I never saw an app that was displaying someting on top of the keyboard, so I'm not sure if this is possible.
Using a plugin, you'll be able to execute native code with javascript events :)

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to overlap the keyboard? Hide parts of the Keyboard?
-> impossible

Do you want to scroll to a certain position or add an element directly above the keyboard?
-> there is a flag, in the AndroidManifest.xml [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

**update 1**

If it is set to **adjustPan** the input element will be directly above the keyboard. Now you can use javascript, to calculate a position above the input element. There you should insert your element with an absolute positioning.

**update 2**

adjustPan may fail, IF you use css: transform() or transform-3d()

Comment: this flag?   android:windowSoftInputMode=["stateUnspecified",
                                       "stateUnchanged", "stateHidden",
                                       "stateAlwaysHidden", "stateVisible",
                                       "stateAlwaysVisible", "adjustUnspecified",
                                       "adjustResize", "adjustPan"]

Comment: How can I tell an object in HTML to be above the keyboard?

Comment: The adjustPan says not rise up all the objects when the keyboard is opened, it is also good, but he did not put the object above the keyboard by clicking on it ..

Comment: This behaviour will only be applied to input-elements.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that's not possible.

The keyboard is implemented by the **OS** itself, you can't overlay stuff over it with JavaScript.

Now, if you want to position a element above the keyboard, instead of overlaying it, take a look at:
[How can I position a layout right above the android on-screen keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220218)

Comment: I ask, because I saw an app that did this.

Comment: @HodayaShalom: What application? do you have screenshots or a link? You might want to add information like that in your question.